# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos a una aplicación externa que estoy mostrando dentro de un Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html5, flex, actionscript

Estoy usando un Iframe para mostrar una aplicación externa y necesito enviar datos desde mi Iframe hacia dicha aplicación.
La aplicación que contiene el iframe esta en actionscript y la que muestro esta usando react. 
He probado varias cosas pero sin ningún resultado.

Les dejo mi código:

**En mi componente en flex:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En el html de mi app Flex:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En mi el index de la app React hice esto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A traves del uso de ExternalInterface.call() puedo llamar a mi función renderURL para crear el iframe y reenderizar la URl que le envio por parametro. Ahora necesito una vez que este reederizado el iframe, pasar datos (un mensage, un string....) a la aplicación que esta embebida. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿qué datos necesita pasarle?, ¿qué errores tiene?, para que la comunidad pueda entenderle, debe primero leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y edite la pregunta.

Comment: ok editare el titulo, en cuanto al cuerpo de la pregunta puse el ejemplo del problema que tengo ahora mismo, quiero poder pasar un dato cualquiera a mi app en react desde mi app en flex. Estoy usando un iframe para mostrar la aplicacion externa que es la que esta en react.

Answer (score -1):

Usar la api post message del navegador fue la solucion que me reslvio este problema!

Comment: Y como fue que usaste esto para resolver tu problema? las respuestas deben ser completas, mira por favor [answer]